# "is there such a thing as" - is this a colloquialism?

Tags: colloquialisms

I've been asked to edit a scholarly paper intended for publication, written by a non-native English speaker.  Somehow I'm just not sure whether "such a thing as" is colloquial or not. I think so, but I don't want to over-correct the paper.

The context is something like this: "In his paper entitled '...', the author Joe Bloggs begins by asking whether there was such a thing as a national identity in [country] in [period]."

The paper referred to there begins with the question: "In what sense, if any, can [country] be said to have had a national identity in [period]?"
(Pardon my square brackets; I'm just trying to keep it anonymous.)

If "such a thing as" is colloquial, I'd rewrite it with something like, " ... asking whether [country] could be said to have had a national identity..." etc.

Looking forward to your comments!  Thanks.

Comment: It’s a matter of personal style.

Comment: With such a deep philosophical/sociological question, you certainly don't want a whiff of informal banter. But in my judgement, 'is there such a thing as ...' works after a more formal phrasing 'In what sense, if any, can [country] be said to have had a national identity in [period]?' (though I'd use the more formal wording first). >> So I _would_ make more formal a standalone synopsis "In his paper entitled '...', the author JB begins by asking whether there was such a thing as a national identity in [country] in [period]." But as Lawrence says, a tricky call. // Your rewrite shifts emphasis.

Comment: Lawrence, I'd agree that the choice of whether or not to use a colloquial phrase is a matter of personal style. But is this phrase colloquial?
Edwin, I looked up the paper my author was referring to. He doesn't quote it; he just notes that the guy had asked whether there was such a thing as...
Maybe I'll just tell him I *think* it's a bit colloquial, and offer a formal formal alternative and let him choose.

Comment: First, "could be said to have had" is not ideal. Second, why do you need "there was *such a thing* as a national identity" at all? Couldn't you ask if *there was a national identity*?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's just asking for writing style advice

Comment: FumbleFingers: I'm not asking whether it's ok to use a colloquialism here - I'm asking whether this _is_ a colloquialism.
Correction to previous comment: "more formal" - not "formal formal".

Comment: @Elise, finding out whether somebody on this site is inclined to label it as *colloquialism* will not solve your problem: what you want to know is whether this phrase will be perceived as out of place in a scholarly journal in a particular field. The answer to that is, I am afraid, bound to be field-specific; only somebody who regularly reads a lot of literature in that filed can have a sense of that.

Comment: jsw29: Thank you. Can I vote for this as the actual answer I needed? (Even though I'd thought I was looking for something else.)

Comment: Here's the problem: Scientists quantify discoveries rather than get caught using the Valley Girl speak of "No, Mom, Wifi isn't a question. It's a *thing*." So it's not doing Joe any favors to quote such spacey talk. If France held a national identity in the 1800s, maybe Joe asked *if that was true* or *how accurate that was*.

Comment: Here's the problem: Scientists quantify discoveries rather than get caught using the Valley Girl speak of "No, Mom, Wifi isn't a question. It's a *thing*." So it's not doing Joe any favors to quote such spacey talk. If France held a national identity in the 1800s, maybe Joe asked *if that was true* or *how accurate that was.*

Answer (score 0):

*If "such a thing as" is colloquial, I'd rewrite it with something like, " ... asking whether [country] could be said to have had a national identity..." etc.*

Without knowning more about the context of your question, I think your interpretation of the actual meaning of this phrase is correct. It's quite subtle given its use of English language phraseology, but I believe you've correctly described it. The author is wondering, or even suggesting that a country may not have a national identity at this stage of its development.

Comment: But is it colloquial? (See original question.)

Answer (score 0):

The phrase *is there such a thing as* is not a [***colloquialism***](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/colloquialism) in this sense:

> [Merriam-Webster]
> **1 a** : a colloquial expression
>        // "Chicken out" is a *colloquialism* for "to lose one's nerve."
> **1 b** : a local or regional dialect expression
>        // "Bodacious" originated as a Southern *colloquialism*.

In other words, it's not a set *expression* in the same kind of sense as an idiom.

However, it would likely still be considered [***colloquial***](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/colloquial) with respect to very formal writing:

> [Merriam-Webster]
> **1 a** : used in or characteristic of familiar and informal conversation
>        // In *colloquial* English, "kind of" is often used for "somewhat" or "rather."
> *also* : unacceptably informal
> **1 b** : using conversational style
>        // a *colloquial* writer

In other words, if the context were a scientific journal, common style guidance would likely rate the following sentences in the following way (I am paraphrasing slightly):

> ✘ Such a thing as a black hole without gravity does not exist.
> ✔ Black holes without gravity do not exist.

But the degree of acceptable informality, and what's considered formal, will vary based on context, publisher, and audience.

While I'd say that *is there such a thing as* (or just *such a thing as*) is slightly colloquial, I wouldn't personally necessarily reject it any of the kinds of essays I used to write.